# How to make state update for two independent modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-hooks

I am new to react and have been stuck on this problem for two days. When logging in you can choose client or merchant and are redirected to the appropriate place. I need to pass the data from the client side to the merchant side but although the client side updates when submitting in the input, the merchant side does not. Is there any way that this is possible even though the components have different routes? What I am trying to use is redux stores but that does not seem to be working.

**src/client/FirstForm.js**

```
import React, {createRef, useState} from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { addBird, incrementBird } from '../store/birds/birds';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

function FirstForm() {

    const handleInputChange = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({
            prodDetails : event.target.value
        })
    }
    const [birdName, setBird] = useState('');
    const birds = useSelector(state => state.birds);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        dispatch(addBird(birdName))
        setBird('');
      };

    return (
    <div className="input-container" id="subtitle-space">
    <input type="text"onChange={e => setBird(e.target.value)} value={birdName}/>
    <button type="submit" className="btn" onClick={handleSubmit}>
    </div>
    );   
}   

const mapStateToProps= state => {
    return {
        birds : state.birds
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        addBird: () => dispatch(addBird())
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(FirstForm);
```

****src/merchant/Merchant.js****

```
function Merchant(props) {

    const birds = useSelector(state => state.birds);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    return (
          <div className="placeholder">
            <h>{birds.map(bird => (<h>{bird.name} <br></br></h>))}</h>
          <div> )
           );
}

export default withRouter(Merchant);
```

**src/index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import birdApp from './store/birds/birds';

const store = createStore(birdApp);

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

// If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
// unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
// Learn more about service workers: 
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

**src/store/birds.js**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
const ADD_BIRD = 'ADD_BIRD';
const INCREMENT_BIRD = 'INCREMENT_BIRD';

export function addBird(bird) {
  return {
    type: ADD_BIRD,
    bird,
  }
}

export function incrementBird(bird) {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_BIRD,
    bird
  }
}

const defaultBirds = [
  {
    name: 'robin',
    views: 1,
  }
];

function birds(state=defaultBirds, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_BIRD:
      state.push(
        {
          name: action.bird,
          views: 1
        })
      return state
    case INCREMENT_BIRD:
      const bird = state.find(b => action.bird === b.name);
      const birds = state.filter(b => action.bird !== b.name);
      return [
        ...birds,
        {
          ...bird,
          views: bird.views + 1
        }
      ];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

const birdApp = combineReducers({
  birds
});

export default birdApp;
```

**Here also is my Client component src/client/client.js:**

```
import React,{ useEffect } from 'react'; //for later security
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import './Client.css';
import '../common/Button.css';
import '../common/TopBar.css';
import Boxes from './Boxes';
import FirstForm from './FirstForm';
import SecondForm from './SecondForm';
import ThirdForm from './ThirdForm';
import RequestNow from './RequestNow';



class Client extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      }
    }
    render() {
    return(
        <div>
          {/* Request now button */}
          <RequestNow></RequestNow> 

          {/* Boxes in middle */}
          <Boxes></Boxes>

          {/* Request now first form */}
          <FirstForm></FirstForm>

          {/* Request now second form */}
          <SecondForm></SecondForm>

          <ThirdForm></ThirdForm>

        </div>
      )
    }
}


export default withRouter(Client);
```

**This is the login form src/components/loginform/LoginForm.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import {API_BASE_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME} from '../../constants/apiContants';
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import "../../common/Button.css";
import "../../common/Security.css";

function LoginForm(props) {
    const [state , setState] = useState({
        email : "",
        password : "",
        successMessage: null,
        client : false,
        merchant : false
    })
    const handleChange = (e) => {
        const {id , value} = e.target   
        setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [id] : value
        }))
    }
    const redirectToClient = () => {
        props.updateTitle('Client')
        props.history.push('/client');
    }
    const redirectToMerchant = () => {
        props.updateTitle('Merchant')
        props.history.push('/merchant');
    }
    const handleClient = () => {
        //Only select if client is unselected
        if(state.client === false) {
            state.client = true;
            state.merchant = false;

            document.getElementById("client").className = "left button-selected";
            document.getElementById("merchant").className = "right button-unselected";
        }
    } 
    const handleMerchant = () => {
        //Do nothing if merchant is already selected
        if(state.merchant === false) {
            state.merchant = true;
            state.client = false;
            
            document.getElementById("merchant").className = "right button-selected";
            document.getElementById("client").className = "left button-unselected";
        }
    } 
    const handleSubmitClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if(state.client === false && state.merchant === false) {
            props.showError('Please select client or merchant');
        }
        else {
        const payload={
            "email":state.email,
            "password":state.password,
        }
        axios.post(API_BASE_URL+'/user/login', payload)
            .then(function (response) {
                if(response.status === 200){
                    setState(prevState => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        'successMessage' : 'Login successful. Redirecting to home page..'
                    }))
                    localStorage.setItem(ACCESS_TOKEN_NAME,response.data.token);
                    if(state.client) {
                        redirectToClient();
                        }
                    else if(state.merchant) {
                        redirectToMerchant();
                    }
                    props.showError(null)
                }
                else if(response.code === 204){
                    props.showError("Username and password do not match");
                }
                else{
                    props.showError("Username does not exists");
                }
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }}
    const redirectToRegister = () => {
        props.history.push('/register'); 
        props.updateTitle('Register');
    }
    return(
        <div className="card col-12 col-lg-4 login-card mt-2 hv-center">
            <form>
                <div className="form-group text-left">
                <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                <input type="email" 
                       className="form-control" 
                       id="email" 
                       aria-describedby="emailHelp" 
                       placeholder="Enter email" 
                       value={state.email}
                       onChange={handleChange}
                />
                <small id="emailHelp" className="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</small>
                </div>
                <div className="form-group text-left">
                <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input type="password" 
                       className="form-control" 
                       id="password" 
                       placeholder="Password"
                       value={state.password}
                       onChange={handleChange} 
                />
                </div>
                <div className="form-check">
                </div>
                <div className="btnContainer" id="clientMerchButton">
                    <span id="client" class="left button-unselected"
                        onClick={handleClient}>
                    Client</span>

                    <span id="merchant" class="right button-unselected"
                        onClick={handleMerchant}>
                    Merchant</span>
                </div> <br></br> <br></br>
                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    className="btn btn-primary"
                    id="loginSubmit"
                    onClick={handleSubmitClick}
                >Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div className="alert alert-success mt-2" style={{display: state.successMessage ? 'block' : 'none' }} role="alert">
                {state.successMessage}
            </div>
            <div className="registerMessage">
                <span>Dont have an account? </span>
                <span className="loginText" onClick={() => redirectToRegister()}>Register</span> 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default withRouter(LoginForm);
```

Comment: as i've understand, you have two routes: `merchant` and `client`, can you post your `router` component and the `client` component as well, and tell us what data you want to pass exactly?

Comment: I've edited my post. For now I am just trying to pass the updated birds array as a test (which have a name and views). submitting to the form in FirstForm.js should add elements to the birds array and this update is not being shown on the merchant side even though it does appear on the client side FirstForm.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't able to spot the problem yet, but I've noticed the strange jsx element 'h'
```<h>{birds.map(bird => (<h>{bird.name} <br></br></h>))}</h>```, did you mean `h1`?, and can you try to console.log the `birds` variable too in your `Merchant` component and see what you have.

Comment: That was just to display all the elements of the birds list on the client side. When I console.log(birds) on the merchant side all that I get is the initial state of the bird which is just {name : 'robin', value : 1} with no additional birds added

Comment: Your code in `Merchant` looks okay, but can you try to use the `connect` function instead of `useSelector` just to be sure 
```
function Merchant(props){

    console.log({props})
    //...
}

const mapStateToProps= state => {
    return {
        birds : state.birds
    }
}


export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(Merchant));
```

Comment: I tried that but it is not working.

Comment: Sorry for that, if you can put your code (or the part that causes the issue) in a code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/) and reproduce the issue we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the up-to-date code then you need to use handleSubmit for on button clicked as I cant see handleSubmit used anywhere. Also it would be better to use handleChange function on onChange.

```
 <div className="input-container" id="subtitle-space" onSubmit="handleSubmit">
    <input type="text"onChange={handleInputChange} value={birdName}/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send Request">
 </div>
```

And mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps are not required as you are already using useDispatch and useSelector

Comment: I forgot to include the button in my post but it is now there. The problem I am having is the data updating in the merchant side because it is updating on the client side.

Comment: do   const ```birds = useSelector(state => state.birds); ``` also updates in client
and can you try 
 ```case ADD_BIRD:
    return{
      ...state,
     name: action.bird
    }```
instead of push in reducer